# NodeJS: Accessing object fields returns undefined even though fields exist

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next){console.log(req.params.id)
  request(
    config.API_URL + "/v1/gallery/get?id=" + req.params.id, 
    function (err, response, body){
      console.log('###BODY###',JSON.stringify(body));
      console.log('###BODY###',JSON.stringify(body.data));
      res.render('gallery', { user: req.session.user, gallery: body.data, title: 'Gallery', purchased: req.session.user.outlet ? (req.session.user.outlet.purchased || []) : [], config: config });
    }
  );
});
```

I'm trying to pass the request body's data field as the gallery for this template, but upon passing `body.data`, in the template it says my gallery argument is undefined.  As you can see above, I then console logged the body and then its field.  `console.log(body)` yields the following output:

`###BODY### "{\"err\":null,\"data\": {\"_id\":\"5d955d7431d34f862a0dbd60\",\"owner
\":null,\"caption\":\"A suspected shooting at the Washington DC Navy Yard has sh
ut down parts of the city. This is the same location where a gunman killed 12 pe
ople in 2013. After an investigation search, authorities gave the \\\"all clear.
\\\"\",\"tags\":[\"dc\",\"navyyard\",\"shooting\",\"washington\"]...`

I shortened the output, but as you can see, the data field is clearly there next to `data.err`.  However, when I run `console.log('###BODY###',JSON.stringify(body.data))`, I am returned `###BODY### undefined`.  Can anyone explain this behavior please?

Comment: Is `body` a string? It's possible you need to perform a `body = JSON.parse(body)` first.

Comment: the hint is in the fact that the stringified json you are getting is escaped. json isn't supposed to be escaped like that, so, you're likely double stringifying it.

Comment: You're right, thank you!  I was copy and pasting without paying attention and didnt grab a request with json set to true

Comment: @MikeC is of course right (the response was a body, instead of a string). I do recommend using the `json: true` configuration option over `JSON.parse(body)` in this case, though. This will make sure that if the response fails to parse as JSON, that error is passed to the callback, rather than throwing an exception.

Answer (score 3):

Replace this:

```
request(
    config.API_URL + "/v1/gallery/get?id=" + req.params.id,
    <callback>
);
```

With:

```
request({
    url: config.API_URL + "/v1/gallery/get?id=" + req.params.id,
    json: true
}, <callback>);
```

That will instruct `request` to automatically parse the response body as `json` (assuming you're using [this request module](https://github.com/request/request), of course).

Comment: Thank worked, thank you!  I copy and pasted and paid no attention to the content type, I guess I deserved that.